# Connecting website its w3wp#X process in performance monitor

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I am trying to connect the Performance Monitor's counters for IIS app poll/website, to the actual website.

I know that :

```
%windir%/system32/inetsrv/appcmd list wp
```

will give me process IDs of the website, and that I can see the process ID of w3wp#X using "process/ID Process". However, this does not seem accurate for me, and when I look at ".NET CLR Memory/Process ID", it does not match "process/ID Process" but seems to be accurate.

can anyone shed some light on this?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

.NET CLR Memory Process ID: This counter displays the process ID of the CLR process instance being monitored. The value displayed will be 0 until after the first garbage collection.

process ID Process: ID Process is the unique identifier of this process. ID Process numbers are reused, so they only identify a process for the lifetime of that process.

Comment: thank you Jalpa but this is straight from the documentation, which I have read, but it does not answer my question as far as I can tell